# aws api http gateway data transfer pricing calculation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

Can someone explain the data transfer pricing for the new aws api gateway http offering when connecting to an ec2 back-end.

According to the pricing model [aws api pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/) it quotes "*HTTP APIs are metered in 512 KB increments." does this include the data trasfer cost if connecting to a ec2 or do you have to effectively count the transaction twice, firstly the data charge from ec2 to api gateway then that data processed by the gateway OR is it a single charge for only data processed by the gateway and therefore not charges between ec2 and the gateway?

Answer (score 0):

From a link below, I can say you have to pay for both transfer fee.
API gateway not include in free list(only free for internal transfer via internal IP)

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Comment: This answer is incorrect, only data transfer out is charged.

Comment: @numX think twice before say something.

Comment: you should consider doing that yourself first. If you check https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/ and https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=761143 you will see that there are even cost pricing examples and nowhere is the double charging mentioned. If you have any proof to the contrary please provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Data transfer to connect to the EC2 backend is not charged, only data transfers outwards are charged. Ref:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=761143